# i want to get channel history whith pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I want to select all the posts that already exist in a Telegram channel with py-telegram-bot-api and send them somewhere

i used get_chat_history but py-telegram-bot-api has no this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible.
There's no way you can get a chat history (posts, messages, joins, lets).
You can only get the future or present chat dara.
Use `@bot.chat_member_handler()` , `@bot.channel_post_handler()` , `@bot.edited_channel_post_handler(`) , `@bot.chat_join_request_handler()` , `bot.get_chat_permissions` , etc.